# Facebook Dynamic Product Ads

Tags: magento-1.9, facebook

Can somebody help me implemented this script? Any advice is appreciated. Thank You.

For product page:

```
     <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '<FB_PIXEL_ID>');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', { 
        content_type: 'product',
        content_ids: ['1234'],    
        content_name: 'ABC Leather Sandal',
        content_category: 'Shoes',
        value: 0.50,
        currency: 'USD'
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For cart page you can use the following piece of code:
>
> ```
> <?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
> $productIds = "";
> foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item):
>     if($item->getParentItemId()) continue;
>     if (strlen($productIds)==0){
>         $productIds = "'".$item->getSku()."'";
>     }
>     else{
>         $productIds = $productIds.",'".$item->getSku()."'";
>     }
> endforeach;?>
>
> <script>
> fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
>      content_name: 'Shopping Cart',
>      content_ids: [<?php echo $productIds?>],
>      content_type: 'product',
>      value: <?php echo number_format($quote->getGrandTotal(),2,'.','');?>,
>      currency: '<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();?>'
> });
> </script>
> ```
>
> For purchase or order confirmation page you can use the following
>   piece of code -:
>
> ```
> <?php $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
>     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
> $productIds = "";
> foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item):
>     if($item->getParentItemId()) continue;
>     if (strlen($productIds)==0){
>         $productIds = "'".$item->getSku()."'";
>     }
>     else{
>         $productIds = $productIds.",'".$item->getSku()."'";
>     }
> endforeach;?>
>
> <script>
> fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
>      content_name: 'Order Confirmation',
>      content_ids: [<?php echo $productIds?>],
>      content_type: 'product',
>      value: <?php echo number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2,'.','');?>,
>      currency: '<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();?>'
> });
> </script>
> ```

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33201068/158325

---

Untested, but should work.  If you are wanting all categories associated you'll need to loop over another collection of the products associated categories to build a list.

```
<?php $_category = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>

<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '<FB_PIXEL_ID>');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', { 
        content_type: 'product',
        content_ids: ['<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getEntityId() ?>'],    
        content_name: '<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getName() ?>',
        content_category: '<?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>',
        value: <?php echo $this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice() ?>,
        currency: '<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I already did the cart page and success page, my issue is with product page ( viewcontent event).

Comment: Sorry, Added an answer for the product detail page.

Comment: It's not working. When i do this, my product page it's not loading. I get a blank page.

Comment: Was my mistake, it's working everything but category name.